# Internal working of Java Map.containsKey() method

Tags: java, hashmap, containskey, object-comparison

I am using a Map<Map, Boolean> in java and when I am trying to validate the Map with containsKey() method, it is returning always false, the inner Map always updates its keys & values. Here is the code which looks like similar to this

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

public class ExampleMap
{
    private static Map<Map<Long,Boolean>, Boolean> objectDetailsToSize= new HashMap<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Random rn = new Random();
        int size = 10;
        Map<Long,Boolean> detailsMap = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i=0; i< size; i++)
        {
            detailsMap.put(rn.nextLong(),rn.nextBoolean());
            if(!objectDetailsToSize.containsKey(detailsMap))
            {
                    objectDetailsToSize.put(detailsMap, rn.nextBoolean());
                    System.out.println("Why containsKey() method is failing here");
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Why Map's containsKey() method is always failing here?

Answer (score 0):

You must make a new `detailsMap` -- or copy your existing one -- every time through the loop.  Right now, you're modifying the map that you've already put in.